# How to pick Kubernetes Ingress controller

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

What do I need to take into comparison to pick the kubernetes ingress controller / load balancer?

For example, I found [this](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) fancy implementation of Azure Application Gateway as ingress controller. But what are the benefits of using this setup compared to the simplest nginx or maybe traefik?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ingress Controller components are based on a *contract*, to allow external traffic to impact the internal workload using a predefined YAML representation (the *Ingress* resource).

Each Ingress Controller provides further features, like *NGINX Ingress Controller* with web-socket support or Traefik that provides HTTP/2 and gRPC support with ease, till the new HAProxy that allows also TCP/L4 external routing. Some Ingress Controller also provide additional features, like Traefik (and HAProxy as well), like a simpler Circuit Breaker implementation thanks to Kubernetes annotations.

First of all, you have to understand which kind of feature you really *want* and *need* and, finally, also considering your knowledge to debug the whole stuff, even considered the community is always available to support other people.